# Using comma before a non-essential reduced relative clause which describes the object of the main clause

Tags: sentence-construction, grammaticality, participles

I am really confused about dangling phrases. Which sentences below are grammatically correct?  I think just 1 and 4 are correct here?

> 1- Did you read Hamlet,  which was written by William Shakespeare?
>
> 2- Did you read Hamlet, written by William Shakespeare? (Is it a
>   dangling participle phrase?)
>
> 3- Did you read Hamlet written by William Shakespeare?
>
> ---
>
> 4- Do you know my brother Ben , who lives in Hong Kong.
>
> 5- Do you know my brother Ben, living in Hong Kong. (Is it a dangling
>   participle phrase? )
>
> 6- Do you know my brother Ben living in Hong Kong.

Comment: None of those have dangling participles. Sentence 3 uses a *restrictive* clause by virtue of not using a comma; it indicates there is more than one book titled *Hamlet* and more than one author, and is asking you about the specific one authored by Hamlet. In sentences 4–6, *my brother Ben* is a restrictive clause that indicates you have at least two brothers—and that you're talking about the specific brother named Ben. In sentence 6, not only are you talking about a specific brother, but the lack of a comma after *Ben* indicates the *other* brother or brothers *do not* live in Hong Kong.

Comment: All of those sentences are grammatical. Actually, one interpretation of *living* could be that *you* live in Hong Kong. In that interpretation, the word *living* could result in an ambiguous referent. But that's because of the word used, not the comma or lack thereof. And it doesn't specifically match the definition of a *dangling participle*, but it does produce a similar confusion.